# Implementing ioctl inside the kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am working on Linux kernel 4.19.2. I want to read performance counters available without using perf or any such tool.

From the userspace, I use code as follows.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/perf_event.h>
#include <asm/unistd.h>

#define rdpmc(counter,low,high) \
     __asm__ __volatile__("rdpmc" \
        : "=a" (low), "=d" (high) \
        : "c" (counter))

void test(){
    printf(".");


}


static long
perf_event_open (struct perf_event_attr *hw_event, pid_t pid,
         int cpu, int group_fd, unsigned long flags)
{
  int ret;

  ret = syscall (__NR_perf_event_open, hw_event, pid, cpu, group_fd, flags);
  return ret;
}





int
main ()
{
  unsigned long values1, values2;
  unsigned int fixed0, low, high;
  struct perf_event_attr pe;
  int fd, i;

  fixed0 = (1 << 30);

  memset (&pe, 0, sizeof (struct perf_event_attr));
  pe.type = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE;
  pe.size = sizeof (struct perf_event_attr);
  pe.config = PERF_COUNT_HW_INSTRUCTIONS;
  pe.disabled = 1;
  pe.exclude_kernel = 0;
  pe.exclude_user = 0;
  pe.exclude_hv = 0;
  pe.exclude_idle = 0;

  fd = perf_event_open (&pe, 0, -1, -1, 0);
  if (fd == -1)
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "Error opening leader %llx\n", pe.config);
      exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
for (i=1; i<=50; i++)
{
  ioctl (fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET, 0);
  ioctl (fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, 0);

  rdpmc (fixed0, low, high);
  values1 = ((unsigned long) high << 32) + (unsigned long) low;

  test();

  rdpmc (fixed0, low, high);
  values2 = ((unsigned long) high << 32) + (unsigned long) low;

  ioctl (fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_DISABLE, 0);
  printf (" %lu\n", values2 );  
}
  close (fd);
}
```

Now I want to implement the same thing in the kernel code.

My goal is that, at every context switch get the count of an event and store it in the task structure. Hence eventually I want the counter to be called from the context_switch() function in the kernel. If I do it from the kernel then I will have the advantage of always running in the context of the current thread.

I think most of the code can be reused from the kernel as well.
I am not sure about the ioctl() part though.

Comment: @sourcejedi This ioctl() would be calling something in the kernel right? I want to do it from there directly. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @NikhileshSingh understood.  You might be missing "good taste" for design :-P.  But I basically ignored your Q1.  It's not just that Q1 is very broad and vague. You don't explain why you are using this code in the first place.  It is very hard to guess what you are missing, I don't know what you *do* have!

Comment: @sourcejedi I have added my complete code. Hope the description helps.

Comment: @NikhileshSingh I assume that doesn't crash, but your program does not explain unambiguously on its own.  You are reading a per-cpu counter.  You have not shown what your intention is v.s. Linux choosing to migrate your process between different cpus while it is running.  Your english language description doesn't say anything about which CPU(s) you want counter values from either.

Comment: Also you still haven't explained why you think you can do the `__NR_perf_event_open()` part from the kernel.  Why are you confident about that part, but you need to ask about `ioctl()` ?  That would be a nice clear way to show "where you got stuck", and the specific answer you seem to be looking for.

Comment: @sourcejedi The __NR_perf_event_open() gives me a number mapped to the syscall, which I believe can be called from the kernel code as well. Something on the lines of http://www.linux.it/~rubini/docs/ksys/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90991/discussion-between-nikhilesh-singh-and-sourcejedi).

Comment: I was going to suggest if this should have been on SO, but you seem to have already posted this there, too: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55100453/6372809

Comment: @ilkkachu Yes, the discussion there was very broad, I wanted to narrow it down to a particular minute topic here.

Comment: @NikhileshSingh please be aware that cross-posting like this is a specific reason for getting your question closed - sometimes on *both* sites!  If you ask a complex question in two different places at the same time, it can lead to duplicated effort.  It is not very respectful.  If you manage to cross-post the question without some necessary detail, which *was* present in the older question, that's not great either.

Comment: @sourcejedi Oh, the question on SO deals more with the idea and the one here is more about implementation. Should I remove one of these?

Comment: @NikhileshSingh Thanks for asking. I *think* at this point, it's enough to leave this question as closed.  ("on hold" will change to "closed" after a day or so).  PS: I have edited my answer again.

Comment: @NikhileshSingh, hmm, ok, I didn't really quite catch what the difference between the two was. I'm not exactly sure how much experience in kernel programming people have here, vs. in SO, but as the [site topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is currently written, even kernel programming seems to fall under SO's wide umbrella. And you did get an answer to your first question there. Then again, a quick look on the [`linux-kernel` tag there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux-kernel) shows a bunch of unanswered questions so YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, it may be possible to call ioctl inside kernel code.  It is called [ksys_ioctl()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/ident/ksys_ioctl).[*]  Notice how `init/` is the only other code that calls ksys_ioctl().  This is an unusual thing to do, to put it mildly.  Calling *perf* ioctls inside the kernel sounds even more dubious.

**To *start* understanding why this is unusual, I would point out that `ksys_ioctl()` still takes an `fd` argument.  This is the number of a file descriptor *within the context of the current task* (process/thread).**

> [edit] My goal is that, at every context switch get the count of an event and store it in the task structure. Hence eventually I want the counter to be called from the context_switch() function in the kernel.

AAAHHH.

So you did *not* want to call ioctl() from the kernel.  (You would not have a file descriptor to call ioctl() on.  And I do *not* believe you want to start opening file descriptors into the file table of the current task during every context_switch().  Even if you close them afterwards).

At this point, you are asking about implementing (a smaller version of) the Linux `perf` sub-system.  The `perf` subsystem owns the performance counters.  If you want to use the performance counters *without* the `perf` subsystem, you should start by disabling `perf` support in the kernel.  At some later point in the process you should spend time looking at relevant material in the [SDM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm) (or related manuals - I have not checked which).

---

[*] Sidenote: there are limitations when you pass pointers into `ksys_*()` functions.  Basically they expect `__user` memory, not kernel memory, unless you play games using [`set_fs()`](https://lwn.net/Articles/722267/)..

---

Working on the `perf` code would be a different matter.  You can easily find the code to start looking at there, e.g. by clicking on [PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.2/ident/PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET) .  As well as the specific line, that will give you a source file (and directory) to look at, and you can also keep clicking around :-). Therefore I assume that is not your question.

Comment: perf does a lot of sampling and is quite complicated. I just want a mechanism to get some counter values while I am running in the context of a given thread. What do you exactly mean by compiling out perf code, as it's quite complicated.

Comment: @NikhileshSingh https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/PERF_COUNTERS.html